# varags functions that return vargas lambdas lua

Tags: lambda, lua, scope, variadic-functions

If I want to write a function that takes varargs and returns a function that takes vargas I run into ambiguous `...` for example

```
    function bind(func, ...) return function(...)  func(..., ...) end end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you're missing an end to close the bind function.

If you have ambiguities just resolve them by using different names.

```
function bind(func, ...)
  return function(...)  func(..., ...) end
end
```

If we test your code like that: `bind(print, "a", "b", "c")(1,2,3)`

you'll get the output:

> 1 1 2 3

If you have ... or any other name in a functions parameter list, that variable will be a local within the scope of that function. It will have priority over any other variable with the same name in a superior scope. So the ... in your anonymous function has nothing to do with the ... of function bind.

To resolve this problem you could simply do something like

```
function bind(func, ...)
  local a = table.pack(...)
  return function(...)  func(table.unpack(a, 1, a.n), ...) end
end
```

Now calling bind(print, "a", "b", "c")(1,2,3) will output:

> a 1 2 3

To find out what happened to b and c please read this section: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11

(and the rest of Lua's manual of course)

> When a function is called, the list of arguments is adjusted to the
>   length of the list of parameters, unless the function is a vararg
>   function, which is indicated by three dots ('...') at the end of its
>   parameter list. A vararg function does not adjust its argument list;
>   instead, it collects all extra arguments and supplies them to the
>   function through a vararg expression, which is also written as three
>   dots. The value of this expression is a list of all actual extra
>   arguments, similar to a function with multiple results. **If a vararg
>   expression is used inside another expression or in the middle of a
>   list of expressions, then its return list is adjusted to one element**.
>   If the expression is used as the last element of a list of
>   expressions, then no adjustment is made (unless that last expression
>   is enclosed in parentheses).

So something like func(..., ...) will never work, even if ... were two different lists.

To avoid this you have  to contatenate both argument lists.

```
 function bind(func, ...)
  local args1 = table.pack(...)
  return function(...)
      local args2 = table.pack(...)

      for i = 1, args2.n do
          args1[args1.n+i] = args2[i]
      end
      args1.n = args1.n + args2.n

      func(table.unpack(args1, 1, args1.n))
  end
end
```

bind(print, "a", nil, "c")(1,nil,3)

Which finally gives us the desired output:

> a nil c 1 nil 3

But I am sure you can think of a nicer way to achieve your goal without concatenating various varargs.

Comment: Your variant does not hadle nil in argument list

Comment: @moteus yeah missed that one, thanks for the hint. fixed

Answer (score 2):

You can try [vararg](https://github.com/moteus/lua-vararg) library. Which also handles `nil` in arguments.

```
va = require "vararg"

function bind(func, ...)
  local args = va(...)
  return function(...)
      func(va.concat(args, va(...)))
  end
end

bind(print, 1, nil, 2)(3, nil, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach resembles [Rici Lake's Partial](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-01/msg00212.html) which uses memoized helper functions instead of table packing/unpacking. It has a performance advantage roughly 2x faster and has a lower memory usage.

```
local fmt, cat, pack = string.format, table.concat, table.pack

local function args(n,Prefix)  
  local as,prefix = {}, Prefix or '_'
  local step,from,to = n<0 and -1 or 1, n<0 and -n or 1, n<0 and 1 or n
  for i=from,to,step do as[1+#as]=prefix..i end
  return function(sep) return cat(as,sep or ',')end
end

local function paramsCat(...)
  local r,p = {}, pack(...)
  for i=1,p.n do if p[i]:len()>0 then r[1+#r]=p[i] end end
  return cat(r,',')
end

local bind = setmetatable({}, {
  __call = function(self,f,...)
    local narg = select("#",...)
    if not self[narg] then
      local a = args(narg)()
      local b = '...'
      local src = fmt([[
return function(%s) -- _1,_2       
  return function(fn)
    return function(...)
      return fn(%s) -- _1,_2,...
    end
  end
end]],a, paramsCat(a,b))
      local fn = load(src,'_')()
      self[narg] = fn
    end
    return self[narg](...)(f)
  end  
})
```

With slight modification, we can extend the binding to start at nth arguments,

```
local bindn = setmetatable({}, {
  __call = function(self, n, f, ...)
    local narg = select("#",...)
    if type(n)~='number' then -- shifted, n is the function now
      if f~=nil or narg>0 then
        return self(0, n, f, ...)
      else
        return self(0, n)
      end      
    end
    self[n] = self[n] or {}
    if not self[n][narg] then
      local a = args(n)()
      local b = args(narg,'b')()
      local c = '...'
      local src = fmt([[
return function(%s)     -- b1,b2
  return function(fn)
    return function(%s) -- _1,_2,_3,...
      return fn(%s)     -- _1,_2,_3,b1,b2,...
    end
  end
end]],b, paramsCat(a,c), paramsCat(a,b,c))
      local fn = load(src,'_')()
      self[n][narg] = fn
    end
    return self[n][narg](...)(f)
  end  
})

local dp = bindn(2,print,'debug-','print:')
dp(1,2,3,4,5) --> 1 2   debug-  print:  3   4   5
dp = bindn(print,'debug-','print:')
dp(1,2,3,4,5) --> debug-    print:  1   2   3   4   5

string.Bytes = bindn(1,string.byte,1,-1)
print(("Test"):Bytes()) --> 84  101 115 116
```